# ziptastic response text shows 'undefined'

Tags: ajax, undefined, responsetext

I am trying to fetch city and state data from ziptastic using following code

```
function showZipData(){
zipcode = document.getElementById("zipcode").value;
zipData = document.getElementById("divZipDetails")
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open("GET", "http://www.ziptasticapi.com/"+zipcode, true);
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
if(client.readyState == 4)
{
var elements = client.responseText;
alert(elements.city);
alert(elements.state);
}}client.send();}
```

But, both the alerts are returning undefined... Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are simply missing a call to JSON.parse(..)

```
var elements = JSON.parse(client.responseText);
console.log("elements: " + elements);
console.log("elements.city: " + elements.city);
console.log("elements.state: " + elements.state);
```

Works for me!

Comment: If my answer was helpful - please consider voting it up and/or marking it as "best answer". ty